# PINs do not want to go HIGH on the PCB STM32 board

Tags: stm32, led

I just designed my first STM32 PCB board for STM32L476RG flashed it and tried to test it with togglePin. However multimeter doesn't show anything.

Here is the design for the STM32

[image]

- I use nucleo board as a programator by unplagging jumpers and connecting jumper cables to debugger on the PCB board (so that computer can see the stm board)
- I use LDO 5V to 3.3V for a power supply to stm32
  [image]
- Here is my settings for stm32 debug:
  [image]

Although I designed a PCB for JTAG, for flashing microcontroller I use SWD just with JTMS and JTCK

-Here is my clock configuration (i am not using any additional crystal):
[image]

I assigned gpio pins as Output in CubeMX but non of them are not going HIGH.

Any thoughts on that? Or what can I possibly do?

Comment: Are you sure the peripheral clock to the GPIO port is enabled (these are enabled on a port by port basis)? You need to enable this before configuring the port.

Comment: Also have you defined the correct output mode for your circuit? (Push/Pull, Open Drain)? If your GPIO is the PB12-15 it looks like you need push/pull, assuming there are no pull ups/downs on the pin.